Can a Firebase cloud function that is configured to be invoked by a Firestore trigger be called with a GET method?
Can a Firebase cloud function that is configured to be invoked by a Firestore trigger be called with a GET method? I have a Firebase cloud function that is configured to be invoked by a Firestore document creation. My Google Cloud logger identified an attempt at calling this function with an HTTP GET request from httpRequest.userAgent: Chrome 129.0.0.0. The call failed with the following eror: Error: Invalid request, unable to process. How is this possible? And who could have made this call?
